# Google compute engine boot fails after hardware upgrade to Hashwell

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine

I have a f1-micro instance running on [Google Compute Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Compute_Engine) running [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).

Some time ago I got a mail stating that the zone I am using (`us-central1-b`) is going through a hardware upgrade to new [Hashwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_%28microarchitecture%29) servers, and all instances need to be restarted. So, I did restart. I shut down my services, and performed a restart via the developer dev. console.

But the instance never came up - the boot on the new hardware failed, and now I can not log in to the instance with ssh. I will add the serial console content below this.

My main issue is that there are some content I would really like to get my hands on (nope - didn't do a full backup - shoot!).

How do I restore the instance, when I can not log in using ssh?

```
Changing serial settings was 0/0 now 3/0
Start bios (version 1.7.2-20150226_170051-google)
Unable to unlock ram - bridge not found
Ram Size=0x26600000 (0x0000000000000000 high)
Relocating low data from 0x000e5810 to 0x000ef780 (size 2161)
Relocating init from 0x000e6081 to 0x265d3540 (size 51612)
CPU Mhz=2301
=== PCI bus & bridge init ===
PCI: pci_bios_init_bus_rec bus = 0x0
=== PCI device probing ===
Found 4 PCI devices (max PCI bus is 00)
=== PCI new allocation pass #1 ===
PCI: check devices
=== PCI new allocation pass #2 ===
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 0, addr 0000c000, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 0, addr 0000c040, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 1, addr febfe000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 1, addr febff000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: init bdf=00:01.0 id=8086:7110
PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0c
PCI: init bdf=00:01.3 id=8086:7113
Using pmtimer, ioport 0xb008, freq 3579 kHz
PCI: init bdf=00:03.0 id=1af4:1004
PCI: init bdf=00:04.0 id=1af4:1000
Found 1 cpu(s) max supported 1 cpu(s)
MP table addr=0x000fdaf0 MPC table addr=0x000fdb00 size=240
SMBIOS ptr=0x000fdad0 table=0x000fd990 size=314
Memory hotplug not enabled. [MHPE=0xffffffff]
ACPI DSDT=0x265fe070
ACPI tables: RSDP=0x000fd960 RSDT=0x265fe030
Scan for VGA option rom
Machine UUID 2b33f2bc-6042-1f12-c61f-0edd33ff965d
Found 0 serial ports
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@0,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@1,0
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@2,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@3,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@4,0
....
....
....
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@248,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@249,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@250,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@251,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@252,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@253,0
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
PS2 keyboard initialized
All threads complete.
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd920: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 122880 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 6 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000265fe000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000265fe000 - 0000000026600000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
Changing serial settings was 3/2 now 3/0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
Booting from 0000:7c00
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed May 7 23:32:49 UTC 2014
Command line: ro root=UUID=a8cf6ab7-92fb-42c6-b95f-d437f94aaf98 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_NO_LVM console=ttyS0,38400n8 rd_NO_DM
KERNEL supported cpus:
  Intel GenuineIntel
  AMD AuthenticAMD
  Centaur CentaurHauls
Disabled fast string operations
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 (usable)
 BIOS-e820: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000265fe000 (usable)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000265fe000 - 0000000026600000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
DMI 2.4 present.
SMBIOS version 2.4 @ 0xFDAD0
Hypervisor detected: KVM
last_pfn = 0x265fe max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x70106, new 0x7010600070106
Using GB pages for direct mapping
init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000265fe000
RAMDISK: 25f82000 - 265ed02e
ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fd960 00014 (v00 Google)
ACPI: RSDT 00000000265fe030 00034 (v01 Google GOOGRSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: FACP 00000000265fff00 000F4 (v02 Google GOOGFACP 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: DSDT 00000000265fe070 015B6 (v01   GOOG   GODSDT 00000001 INTL 20140214)
ACPI: FACS 00000000265ffec0 00040
ACPI: SSDT 00000000265ff780 0073D (v01 Google GOOGSSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: APIC 00000000265ff660 0006E (v01 Google GOOGAPIC 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: WAET 00000000265ff630 00028 (v01 Google GOOGWAET 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
Setting APIC routing to flat.
No NUMA configuration found
Faking a node at 0000000000000000-00000000265fe000
Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-00000000265fe000
  NODE_DATA [0000000000009000 - 000000000003cfff]
  bootmap [000000000003d000 -  0000000000041cbf] pages 5
(7 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 00265fe000]
  #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
  #1 [0000006000 - 0000008000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
  #2 [0001000000 - 0002020aa4]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0001000000 - 0002020aa4]
  #3 [0025f82000 - 00265ed02e]          RAMDISK ==> [0025f82000 - 00265ed02e]
  #4 [000009fc00 - 0000100000]    BIOS reserved ==> [000009fc00 - 0000100000]
  #5 [0002021000 - 00020210a5]              BRK ==> [0002021000 - 00020210a5]
  #6 [0000008000 - 0000009000]          PGTABLE ==> [0000008000 - 0000009000]
found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000fdaf0] fdaf0
crashkernel=auto resulted in zero bytes of reserved memory.
kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:1c247c1, boot clock
Zone PFN ranges:
  DMA      0x00000001 -> 0x00001000
  DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
  Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x00100000
Movable zone start PFN for each node
early_node_map[2] active PFN ranges
    0: 0x00000001 -> 0x0000009f
    0: 0x00000100 -> 0x000265fe
ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
Setting APIC routing to flat.
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x00] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
SMP: Allowing 1 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000
Allocating PCI resources starting at 26600000 (gap: 26600000:d99bc000)
Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
NR_CPUS:4096 nr_cpumask_bits:1 nr_cpu_ids:1 nr_node_ids:1
PERCPU: Embedded 31 pages/cpu @ffff880002200000 s94872 r8192 d23912 u2097152
pcpu-alloc: s94872 r8192 d23912 u2097152 alloc=1*2097152
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:22167c1, primary cpu clock
Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 154835
Policy zone: DMA32
Kernel command line: ro root=UUID=a8cf6ab7-92fb-42c6-b95f-d437f94aaf98 rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16  rd_NO_LVM console=ttyS0,38400n8 rd_NO_DM
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
xsave/xrstor: enabled xstate_bv 0x7, cntxt size 0x340
Checking aperture...
No AGP bridge found
Memory: 594376k/628728k available (5326k kernel code, 392k absent, 33960k reserved, 7013k data, 1280k init)
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:256
Console: colour *CGA 80x25
console [ttyS0] enabled
allocated 2621440 bytes of page_cgroup
please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
Detected 2299.982 MHz processor.
Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 4599.96 BogoMIPS (lpj=2299982)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Security Framework initialized
SELinux:  Initializing.
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Disabled fast string operations
CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
mce: CPU supports 32 MCE banks
alternatives: switching to unfair spinlock
SMP alternatives: switching to UP code
Freeing SMP alternatives: 36k freed
ACPI: Core revision 20090903
ftrace: converting mcount calls to 0f 1f 44 00 00
ftrace: allocating 21778 entries in 86 pages
Enabling x2apic
Enabled x2apic
APIC routing finalized to physical x2apic.
..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=0 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz stepping 00
Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 63 no PMU driver, software events only.
NMI watchdog disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
Brought up 1 CPUs
Total of 1 processors activated (4599.96 BogoMIPS).
devtmpfs: initialized
regulator: core version 0.5
NET: Registered protocol family 16
ACPI: bus type pci registered
PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
ACPI: Interpreter enabled
ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
ACPI: No dock devices found.
PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0x26600000-0xfebfffff]
PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x26600000-0xfebfffff]
pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs *9)
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
NetLabel: Initializing
NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
Switching to clocksource kvm-clock
pnp: PnP ACPI init
ACPI: bus type pnp registered
pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 131072 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 131072 bind 65536)
TCP reno registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
Freeing initrd memory: 6572k freed
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1430203988.308:1): initialized
HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
msgmni has been set to 1173
alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
ksign: Installing public key data
Loading keyring
- Added public key A760F53BCC8FA210
- User ID: CentOS (Kernel Module GPG key)
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
ipmi message handler version 39.2
IPMI System Interface driver.
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified kcs state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified smic state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified smic state machine at i/o address 0xca9, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified bt state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified bt state machine at i/o address 0xe4, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input1
ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
[Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
GHES: HEST is not enabled!
Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Linux agpgart interface v0.103
crash memory driver: version 1.1
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
�serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 6) is a 16550A
Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2300.003 MHz.
serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
00:05: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
00:06: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 6) is a 16550A
00:07: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input2
Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
i8042.c: Warning: Keylock active.
serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 17
registered taskstats version 1
rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2015-04-28 06:53:10 UTC (1430203990)
Initalizing network drop monitor service
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1280k freed
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 10240k
Freeing unused kernel memory: 800k freed
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1584k freed
dracut: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2
dracut: rd_NO_LUKS: removing cryptoluks activation
dracut: rd_NO_LVM: removing LVM activation
udev: starting version 147
dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
dracut: rd_NO_MD: removing MD RAID activation
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
%GFATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

input: ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory



FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/disk/by-uuid/a8cf6ab7-92fb-42c6-b95f-d437f94aaf98" found




%GFATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.


dracut Warning: Signal caught!

dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff815274ef>] ? panic+0xa7/0x16f
 [<ffffffff81077292>] ? do_exit+0x862/0x870
 [<ffffffff8118a525>] ? fput+0x25/0x30
 [<ffffffff810772f8>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
 [<ffffffff81077387>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
 [<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Comment: As a workaround you may take a snapshot of the disk, create a new disk from it and attach it a secondary disk to a new instance. In this way you should be able to access data.

Comment: Yes - i guess that may be the only way to go. I am no sys-adm, so i don't know all the inns and outs of Linux - or compute-engine for that matter, but of cause i would prefer to be able to "fix" the broken instance some how. I just don't know how - when i can not log into the instance..

It seems odd that the image can not handle the move between the hw platforms. I would have loved if the risk of this had been mentioned in the mail, in which i was told to restart the instance.

Comment: Could you please provide project name, instance name and Centos version?

Comment: projectname and instancename are both 'epraktiklogbogen' (without the pings). I am not sure what the exact centos version is, and can not find the info in the developer console - i created the instance early in 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest at first to follow standard troubleshooting steps to validate the disk's filesystem as [documented](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot).

Then you can try to snapshot the disk and create a new instance with boot disk from snapshot to avoid exclude a disk UUID conflict.

Finally you can try to attach the disk to recover the files to a brand new instance as I suggested in my previous comment.

If you can not validate the filesystem as per troubleshooting guide the data is most probably lost and nothing more can be done to recover it.

Please note as a good practice to take care of either periodic snapshot, GCS differentiual backup or other replication method.

Thank you.
Sincerely,
P.

Comment: Thank you. I will try doing as you suggest, and report back on my results.